# Highlight cells that contain Chr(10)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to highlight all the cells that contain the "Alt + Enter" (aka Chr(10)) character regardless of the other contents of the cell. How can I do this?

Comment: Conditional formatting applied to the cells in question, with a formula like `=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),A1)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub TestForChr()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell, Chr(10)) Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

If you want to start at specific Row or Column, use this:

```
Sub AnotherTestForChr()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long, y As Long

' LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For y = 1 To LastColumn
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, y), Chr(10)) Then
            Cells(i, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is good but it only searches column A, is there a way to get it to search all used columns?

Comment: @Valborg you could add an outside loop to go through `UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Comment: @Valborg I updated the answer. Try it now. And just so you know you can replace the `ActiveSheet` with the sheet name, like this `Application.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange`

Comment: @Valborg The reason you're gettnig an error message is because you are using `Range` instead of `Cells` inside your loops. Replace `Range(y & i)` with `Cells (i, y)`. You should have this `InStr(1, Cells(i, Y), Chr(10))` and this `Cells(i, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`
Hope this helps!